# How to map enum list to string list with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have class A and class B:

```
class A
{
    public List<TypeEnum> Types { get; set; }
    ...

}

class B
{
    public List<string> TypesString { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I am trying to map List to List:

CreateMap<ClassA, CLassB>()
.ForMemebr(destination => destination.TypesString, m => m.ConvertUsing(source => ((byte)source.Types).ToString()))

Outcome:
Desired outcome should be successful mapping from List of enums to List of strings for example: `List<string> => ["1","2","3","5"]`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following mapping configuration:

```
CreateMap<ClassA, CLassB>().ForMember(destination => destination.TypesString, 
                                      opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Types.Select(x => ((byte)x))));
```

Comment: You can remove both `ToString` and `ToList`. AM does that for you.